# While Loop issue when querying Database in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I am having trouble understanding why my codes does not work as I had thought. I am having issue in having my input text value to be that of my resultset value. Let me apologise for my bad explanation. Before I continue, I would like to mention that I am using JSP to run my application.

Say in my database, I have the following names, "Peter", "John" , "Simon" and when I queried, I will store their names in a hidden input text, as the names will be used for other usage. But I am facing the issue where by only "PETER" name is registered in the input text, as Peter is the first entry in the database.

Below is an abstrace of my while loop. If anyone know whats the underlying cause please let me know. Thanks in advance guys.

```
<%while (rs.next()) { %>
<tr><td>
<img alt="logo" src= "<%= rs.getString("ItemImage")%>" width="600" height = "400"/><button type="button" onclick="initialize2()" width="600" >Location</button>
</td>
<td>        
  <input type = 'hidden' id = 'itemName' value = "<%=rs.getString("ItemName")%>" />
  <input type = "hidden" id = "address" value = "<%= rs.getString("ItemLocation")%>" />
  <div id="<%= rs.getString("ItemName")%>" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div> 
</td>
</tr>
<%  } %>
```

Comment: Are you getting any Exception?

Comment: @Braj nope there is no exception. It seems that only the first set of the result are used.

Comment: Please don't embed JDBC code in your JSP. That's so [Model 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the same `id` over and over which registers only one input text.

Try, for example:

```
<% string name = "itemName" + counter; %>
<input type='hidden' name="<%=name%>" value="<%=rs.getString("ItemName")%>" />
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, i noticed that as well and i made some amendments to my codes and its working now! cheers!